# How do i alert a users name when enterd into a prompt

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to alert a users name when the answer it in a prompt box, i have tried

```
    var check=propmt("Enter your name","Name")
    if (check==='') {
    alert("Welcome", + check)
    }
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code. The correct function's name is [prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp). Also, remove the extra "comma" on alert's argument, or put it inside the string. (before edit I though the first argument was a dialog title =S)

Comment: @samuelgrigolato you wouldn't remove the `+` you would remove the `,` because `alert` doesn't accept comma's like `console.log` does.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Spell `prompt` correctly
2. Don't put a `,` before your `+`
3. Change your test so that you alert even if the user enters something other than an empty string

Such:

```
var check=prompt("Enter your name","Name")
if (check !== '') {
    alert("Welcome " + check);
}
```

Comment: And maybe 4, don't ask questions on StackOverflow without checking code :P

Comment: @Bondye or **"Don't use Stack Overflow as your debugger"**

Answer (score 1):

```
if (check==='') {
   alert("Welcome", + check)
}
```

If the check is empty, then say `"welcome" + "empty string"`. That's obviously not what you want.

and that comma is going to cause you some issues.

Should most definitely have a `!` in there.

```
if(check !== '')
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, i have been stuck on that for so long

Answer (score 0):

```
var check=prompt("Enter your name","Name") // you spelled prompt wrong
if (check!=='') { // you had === here
    alert("Welcome" + check); // you had , after "Welcome"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More Appropriate

```
var check=prompt("Enter your name","Name")
if (check!=='' && check!=='Name' ) { 
    alert("Welcome " + check);
}
```